# Precision-recall strange values

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

For whatever reason my precision-recall curve looks weird for MLP. Can someone explain why precision starts at around 0.8 rather than 1 on the left-most section? From my understanding, confidence starts at 1 on the leftmost section, so the classifiers should be predicting 100% negatives.
Image attached below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/INxzG.jpg

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing much about the data but probably imbalance in classes you can check df['class_column'].value_counts()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PR curve, the recall value will go from 0 to 1 (supposing there is at least 1 item of class 1). But the precision might not start at 1.
If the model predicts 100% of probability to be class 1 for a single item that is actually class 0, you can never reach precision of 100% for class 1, because no matter your decision threshold, you will always have this wrongly classified item, even if your model does great on all other items.

I hope this helps, more info [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484227/starting-point-of-the-pr-curve-and-the-aucpr-value-for-an-ideal-classifier).